# Good Database Design for Chapter Tracking App

Tags: database, flutter

I am looking to create an app that tracks weekly chapter releases and allowing users to be able to subscribe to be notified if a new chapter comes up. The following is the database design i am thinking of but have no idea if it is good. Looking for someone to help.

```
User
- Name
- EmailID

Books
- Title
- URL
- Number of Chapters
- Image
- Category

Chapters
- Title
- Chapter Number
- Chapter URL
- Chapter Number

Subscription
- User
- Title
```

The most common operations would be:

1. Show new books/chapters added
2. Show new chapters for books that a user has added

Please let me know if you have any ideas on improving this.

Comment: To judge a database table design, we need to know the business rules. A list of column names does not suffice. We would be be assuming and imaging rules that may not apply to your business,

Comment: ignoring other attributes, you should focus on primary key and foreign key. as your sample, in subscription contain id, user_id. and on books contain id, chapter_id.

Answer (score 0):

Some specific feedback:

- It seems like you've included Chapter Number twice in your Chapter table. Perhaps you meant to make one of those Chapter Title? Alternatively, not all books have a chapter number, so you could simply just have a text Chapter Title field.
- Your user will probably need a **hash** of their password stored in the database.

Some general database design feedback:

- It's often easier to see and reason about the early stages of a database design more visually. An Entity-Relationship model is a great and simple way to model a database that clearly shows the data that will be captured, and very importantly the *relationships* between the data. From this, I can assume that a book has a one-to-many relationship to a chapter, but it would be easier to see this visually.
- Typically entities are singular, so we would have a `Book` table, not a `Books` table.

Answer (score 0):

@BasilBourque has a valid point, but there are some things I can say:

- 'number of chapters' seems redundant. You can query that info from
  the chapters table.
- category is probably not a free format field.
  There are 2 options to do that: with enums and with a foreign key to
  another table. The second one seems more logical. So; add a
  categories table
- what is the primary key of the user? the emailID?
- I would rename the 'Title' fields in all tables except 'Books' to 'Book' or 'Book_title'